# Add only modified files that already exist in the index

Tags: git

Suppose I have 3 tracked files:

```
A.txt
B.txt
C.txt
```

I make changes to B.txt and do:

```
$ git add B.txt
```

Later on I make more changes to both A.txt and B.txt and I want to re-add those changes to B.txt to the index, but not A.txt. If I do this:

```
$ git add -u .
```

This will add both `A.txt` and `B.txt`. However, I want a quick way to add only tracked, modified files to the index that have already been previously added to the index. This would mean that only `B.txt` should be added.

Note: Doing `git add B.txt` isn't an appropriate solution here since my example is contrived. The more complex example has tons of files in my index, but I modify them again, and I want a quick way to update only those files in the index with the new working tree changes.

Comment: Perhaps leave off the `.` and make it just `git add -u`?

Comment: Untested but man page implies it's the right answer: `git update-index --again` (or `-g`).

Comment: @twalberg, I think that `git add -u` is exactly the same as `git add -u .`.  A little test confirms @torek's answer.

Comment: @benjifisher It could be - and I didn't have a chance to test at the time. The way the man page reads though, at least in my mind, implies that there's a (possibly subtle) difference between `git add -u <pathname>` and `git add -u`, even if `<pathname>` is `.`... Could just be worded unclearly, though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `git update-index --again` (`--again` can be abbreviated `-g`):

> ```
>    -g, --again
>        Runs git update-index itself on the paths whose index entries are
>        different from those from the HEAD commit.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

`git diff --cached --name-only` will give you all the files that are already added and ready to be committed.

Executing the following command will only add those files that are already added

```
git add `git diff --cached --name-only`
```

Comment: The documentation for `--name-only` states "Show only names of changed files.", but does this include the full relative path to the file? Otherwise I don't think it will work if it's just giving the file name regardless of its depth within the working tree.

Comment: @RobertDailey: It gives full relative path. For eg, If I add a file say `<app_root>/lib/something.rb`, executing `git diff --cached --name-only` in `<app_root>` will give lib/something.rb

Comment: Note that it will also give you files removed, and if rename detection is enabled, renamed.