# Why does git add --update add new files to the index?

Tags: git

The `-u` flag to `git add` doesn't seem to be working the way it's documented; can someone explain what I'm missing?

The `-u` (or `--update`) flag is documented thus:

```
-u, --update
    Update the index just where it already has an entry matching <pathspec>. This removes as well as
    modifies index entries to match the working tree, but adds no new files.

    If no <pathspec> is given when -u option is used, all tracked files in the entire working tree are
    updated (old versions of Git used to limit the update to the current directory and its
    subdirectories).
```

By my reading of this, a plain `git add -u` should not add any new files to the index, but should only re-add any files that were already staged.  This is the behaviour I want.

However, if I modify a file and then run `git add -u`, the modified file is staged just as though I had not used `-u`. I don't understand how to reconcile this behaviour with the docs statement that it "adds no new files".

Comment: The new files referred in the description of the option are files that are not tracked by Git. The index does not contain only the differences, it is a complete snapshot of the working tree and contains all the tracked files, modified or not. On `git commit` It becomes the next commit.

Comment: @axiac - thank you. According to this link, the "index" is the same as the "staging area" so it should not contain a complete snapshot; only the staged files, correct?
http://shafiul.github.io/gitbook/1_the_git_index.html

Comment: Take a look at the second paragraph of the [description of `git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#_description). Indeed, "index" and "staged area" (and "cache") are different names for the same thing.

Comment: The one I quoted? I don't think it's as clear as you think it is. It says all tracked files in the working tree are "updated" which I took to mean the definition of "update" provided in the preceeding paragraph, which specifies that it adds no new files to the index. I'm getting the feeling that "add a new file to the index" doesn't mean "add a file that's not already in the index" but actually means "add a file that's not tracked". Am I getting closer?

Comment: Perhaps if that first paragraph ended with "adds no untracked files" it might be more clear?

Comment: _"add a file that's not already in the index"_ and _"add a file that's not tracked"_ mean the same thing. [The second paragraph of the description](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#_description) says: _"The "index" holds a snapshot of the content of the working tree, and it is this snapshot that is taken as the contents of the next commit."_ The index does not contain only the modified files or only the changes. It contains the content of all the files tracked by Git, in a certain status. In fact, Git does not track files, it tracks content.

Comment: @Doradus: don't know if "adds no untracked files" would be clearer, but that's the correct meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Really? Can you not have a file that's tracked but not staged?

Comment: @Doradus You cannot haev a file that's tracked but not staged.  Generally you won't see people refer to "staging" a file - rather they talk about staging changes to a file, and you do that by updating the file's image in the index.  But as a number of us have noted, the index contains a complete snapshot - and as I note in my ansewr below, that is why what you are seeing is consistent with the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you maybe don't think index entries exist for everything in the checked out commit; but they do.  Not every index entry is *shown* by `git status` (for example), in just the same way that not every file in your worktree is listed; `status` only shows changes to the index or the worktree.  But "tracked" and "in the index" mean the same thing.

So, that's all `-u` does - it prevents tracking of files that were untracked.  If you want to only commit files for which you've already staged some changes, AFAIK you'll need a custom solution.

Comment: And if my intention is indeed to only update files that have changes in the index (or in the last commit) any pointers to "a custom solution"?

Comment: Found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/22157838/301049 

`git add \`git diff --cached --name-only\``

Answer (score 0):

`git add -u` only adds the files tracked to your staging. If you create a new file and run `git add -u` the new file will not be staged for a commit.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how to reconcile this with the docs saying it "modifies index entries to match the working tree, but adds no new files."

Comment: There is nothing to reconcile. Read what you yourself did. “However, if I modify a file and then run `git add -u`, the modified file is staged”. Yes. That file is _modified_. It is _not new_. So it _is_ staged by   `git add -u`. Just what the docs say will happen. Do you understand what “new” means? “the docs statement that it "adds no new files"” Yup. And this is _not_ a new file. It is a _modified_ file. Get it?

Comment: Mark got it right: I was missing that all tracked files are in the index already even if they're not shown by `git status`. I thought "new" corresponded to "it wasn't shown by `git status` before and now it is".